# Reinforce skills in Java

Tags: java

This past semester I took intro to object oriented programming in java and next semester I will be taking computer science 2 with java which is basically learning about various algorithms and data structures implemented in java such as linked lists, binary trees, etc... 
What are some ways that I can reinforce the knowledge I've learned in my intro to object oriented programming class while still preparing for next semester of algorithms and data structures.

Comment: heu ... study ... book ... pratice ... write own program in java ... you know the usual stuff when your learning something ...

Comment: I have up voted this question as students need proper guidance and direction. For e.g you have suggested to study but what to study and what are some good books?

Comment: Yes I was looking for a more detailed response. It is apparent that reading and practicing programming are all ways to improve, I just wanted guidance on what to read and practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good website that helped me get into java which is called [CodingBat](http://www.codingbat.com/). => It even contains an online compiler to check your solution against some testcases.

After being "done" with codingbat, I started on [ProjectEuler](http://projecteuler.net/) - this one contains the real badass problems :D

I highly suggest checking out those pages.

---

Edit:

Those problems weren't related to the real-world problems I encountered until now. But they surely helped me thinking about code in a different and efficient way.

Coding issues now seem like puzzles to me. Which *immensely* motivates one towards a goal.

Comment: Thanks. I've solved a few problems on Project Euler, and have been working on coding bat every once in a while. Now that I'm on break, I'm gonna try to solve as many as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some programming in java.

Comment: This is the *only* answer.  Yet people keep asking this question apparently hoping for something more magical

Comment: I guess what I meant was what could I program in java. Obviously programming would be the logical thing to do, but exactly what should I program?

Answer (score 2):

These are some interesting problems, so you can solve these problems in Java in order to improve both Java and Algorithm knowledge

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems)

[TopCorder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=help&d2=pracArena) is another good place to start. Just go to algorithm section and launch topcorder arena. Moreover it has some nice tutorials about algorithms.

Good Luck

Comment: Love this, I have to try out some when I get some time :P

Answer (score 0):

From easy => difficult:

- learn/code linked list
- learn/code graphs
- learn/code about red black tree

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to improve your OOP skills and not the problem solving skills. My best suggestion is below and in that order

1. [General Responsibility Assignment Software Principles or GRASP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062)
2. [Practical API Design: Confessions of a Java Framework Architect](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209739)